# Add different class to all levels of parents of a selected link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is my html

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="">Women</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Top</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Short</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Lengthy</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="selected" href="">Child Parent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Medium</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Full Sleve</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Men</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Children</a></li>
<ul>
```

Here I have a class **selected** for a link which is selected. What I need is, I want to add a class to the parent li `<li><a href="">Lengthy</a>`, its top parent `<li><a href="">Top</a>` and its top parent `<li><a href="">Women</a>`

All the parents should have different class.

Please find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3pjrxff/2/

Comment: what are the classes to be added and how is it decided

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h1mogt5m/1/

Comment: Just like active1, active2 like that

Comment: so the above fiddle solves your problem?

Comment: a more easier approach will be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h1mogt5m/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).find("a.selected").each(function(){
        $(this).parents("li").each(function(i, v){
            $(v).addClass('newPar' + i);
        });
    });
});
```

Where i is the index (0, 1, 2 and so on, for different classes), [jQuery.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) gets all parent elements, with the parameter 'li' it only retrieves all li parents.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").attr("href", "#"); // kind of disable all links
$("a").click(function () {
    $("a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).parents("a").addClass("selected");
});
```

});

The problem  with your html is, that the `<a>` are not parents but siblings of the next `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, if you want to add a numerically incremented classes you can use(but then to remove those classes it will be difficult)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $selected = $('.selected');

  var $parents = $selected.parent().parents('li');
  $parents.children('a').addClass(function(i) {
    return 'parent-' + (i + 1)
  });

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.parent-1 {
  color: #00FF00;
}
.parent-2 {
  color: #0000FF;
}
.parent-3 {
  color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Women</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Top</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Short</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lengthy</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="selected" href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Medium</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Full Sleve</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Men</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Children</a></li>
  <ul>
```

---

Another approach will be

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $selected = $('.selected');

  $selected.parent().parents('li').addClass('parent');

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.parent > a {
  color: #00FF00;
}
.parent .parent > a {
  color: #0000FF;
}
.parent .parent .parent > a {
  color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Women</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Top</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Short</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lengthy</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="selected" href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Child Parent</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Medium</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Full Sleve</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Men</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Casuals</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kurthah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Children</a></li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3pjrxff/4/) if you need to add different classes to each parent. This code, however, can be optimized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var curr_parent= $(document).find("a.selected").parent();
   var parent1= $(curr_parent).parent().closest('li');
   $(parent1).addClass('parent1')
   var parent2 = $(parent1).parent().closest('li');
   $(parent2).addClass('parent2')
   var parent3 = $(parent2).parent().closest('li');
   $(parent3).addClass('parent3')

});
```